# Trying to randomly display an image, out of 4 images, based on its src

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, image, random

I have a card game in which I'm trying to randomly display an image out of four four possible images. THE CODEPEN: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/udBan The images are displayed in the html as follows:

```
<html>
<head>
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/main.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/css.css">
</head>
<body>
  <h1>Card Match!</h1>
  <div id="main_image">
    <!-- <div> -->
      <div><img src="images/back-of-card.png"></div>
      <div><img src="images/back-of-card.png"></div>
      <div><img src="images/back-of-card.png"></div>
      <div><img src="images/back-of-card.png"></div>
      <div id="button_div">
        <button id="start">Start Game</button>
        <button id="reset">Reset Game</button>
        <button id="cheat">Cheat</button>
      </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

I have the functionality going such that when you click on a card, it will randomly change it to either a king or a queen. Crazy intense game, I know.

Note the cheat button.

The function that I wrote is:

```
var king_array = ["images/King.png","images/King.png"];
var queen_array = ["images/Queen.png","images/Queen.png"];
$(function() {
  $("#cheat").click(function() {
    if (king_array.length == 1){
      src = king_array.shift();
      back_of_card_array = $('img:not([src="images/King.png"])');
      random = Math.floor(Math.random() * back_of_card_array.length);
      back_of_card_array[random].attr('src',src);
      console.log("turned king");
    } else if (queen_array.length == 1){
      src = queen_array.shift();
      back_of_card_array = $('img:not([src="images/Queen.png"])');
      random = Math.floor(Math.random() * back_of_card_array.length);
      back_of_card_array[random].attr('src',src);
      console.log("turned queen")
    } else {
      console.log("turn a card to cheat!")
    }
  });
});
```

What I was expecting this to do was return an array of the unflipped cards `back_of_card_array = $('img:not([src="images/King.png"])');`,which it does, and then when I click the `cheat` button, to use `back_of_card_array[random].attr('src',src);` to select a randomized image and set it to src, which was either king or queen, depending on what was already flipped (I guess if both a king and a queen are flipped it will turn a king...another issue that I don't intend to get into here).

Thus, how can I get an unflipped card to flip, based on what is already flipped?

Thanks! http://codepen.io/anon/pen/udBan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure I follow your question, but I'll take a swing.

So I'm not clear on the rules of your game, but it sounds like you want to flip either a king or a queen, such that if a King is already face-up you show a queen, and vice versa. Is that right?

If so, I'd maintain an object of flipped cards (if order is important, keep that by making it an array and just pushing in each one as you go).  Then you can either brute force your way through the array (i.e. re-randomizing if the card doesn't match your criteria) or else have two decks (one that's all kings, one that's all queens) and use deck selection to force the right "kind" of card.

Comment: in actually it's the opposite: if there is already a king flipped then I want pressing "cheat" to flip a king.

Comment: I currently have two arrays, with king and queen inside, which allow the flipping to occur. I'll make a codepen...